# How to force Automapper to overwrite array property?

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

I am using Automapper in my project to map business entities to DTO.

```
public class TransportStop
{
    public Point[] Points { get; set; }
}

public class TransportStopDto
{
    public PointDto[] Points { get; set; }

    public TransportStopDto()
    {
        Points = new PointDto[0];
    }
}
```

In constructor I am initializing Points property with an empty array to make sure it is always not null. I am using basic configuration for mapping.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Point, PointDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<TransportStop, TransportStopDto>();

TransportStop stop = new TransportStop()
{
    Points = new Point[]
    {
        new Point() { X = 1, Y = 1 },
        new Point() { X = 2, Y = 2 }
    }
};

TransportStopDto dto = Mapper.Map<TransportStop, TransportStopDto>(stop);
```

With Automapper 2.0.0 it worked just fine, but after upgrading to version 2.2.0 I get mapping exception with inner exception:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

It seems Automapper tries to map every member of array, instead of overwriting the whole array. If I remove property initialization from constructor and leave it null, everything works.

Is it possible to configure Automapper 2.2.0 to always overwrite existing array property with new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by downgrading to version 2.0.0.

Comment: Have you created ticket on Project site https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper ?